# Changing button from disabled to enabled when both data attributes are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the button from disabled to enabled when both data-attributes are NOT empty.

I dont get any errors but everytime I fill the data-attributes its not changing its disabled/enabled attribute.

I've tried it like this but nothing is happening, my browsers console isnt printing out anything.

```html
<select class="form-control os" name="os">
  <option disabled selected>Please choose...</option>
  <option>Ubuntu Server 18.04</option>
  <option>Ubuntu Server 16.04</option>
  <option>Ubuntu Server 14.04</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control location" name="location">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose...</option>
  <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
  <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="Sao Paulo">São Paulo</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right btn-buynow" data-shoppy-product="ewAfime" data-shoppy-os="" data-shoppy-location="" disabled>Buy now</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.location").change(function(){
        var selectedLocation = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $('.btn-buynow').attr('data-shoppy-location', selectedLocation);
    });
    $('select.os').change(function() {
        var selectedOS = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $('.btn-buynow').attr('data-shoppy-os', selectedOS);
    });

    var $buynow = $('.btn-buynow');
    if (typeof $buynow.data('shoppy-os') !== 'undefined' && typeof $buynow.data('shoppy-location') !== 'undefined') {
      if($buynow.attr('disabled')) $buynow.removeAttr('disabled');
      else $buynow.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: And why should it? You're not logging anything to the console.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite unfamiliar with jquery/javascript, I've tried to log to the console with console.log(); but its not printing anything

Comment: Should you instead be checking if the data attribute exists? What you are doing only returns true if the data attribute is not an empty string, or if the value is 0 or false. To check for the actual existence of the data attribute you should use typeof($buynow).data(“data-shoppy-os”) !== “undefined”

Comment: Please post your (relevant, [mcve]) HTML in your question as well in order that we can see what you're doing, and his to reproduce the problem. Linking to a JS Fiddle is a useful extra, but your Friday coffee must be in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

- While accessing `data` attributes using `.data()`, strip the `data-` from the argument
- To `disable` a button, use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

```js
var $buynow = $('.btn-buynow');
if ($buynow.data('shoppy-os') && $buynow.data('shoppy-location')) {
  if($buynow.attr('disabled')) $buynow.removeAttr('disabled');
  else $buynow.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn-buynow" data-shoppy-os="a" data-shoppy-location="b" disabled>Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isnt working for me though. I'm getting the data value from two different dropdown menus, should I add it into the change event?

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet for better understanding of the problem? Additionally, if you are changing values and based on that you want the button to be enabled/disabled then you need to have change event

Comment: This isnt working correctly. When I choose from the first dropdown the button already gets enabled.

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: It should be enabled when both data-attributes have values.

Comment: This is working correctly. Thank you! But on my website, not in the jsfiddle, when I refresh the page the data attributes are empty again but the button is still enabled, it only gets disabled when I refresh with clearing cache (STRG+F5), can I prevent this?

Comment: You can call the function on load as well

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few changes for my method of validation to work. They are as follows:

HTML Changes: adding values to HTML options

```
<select class="form-control os" name="os">
  <option value="Please choose..." selected>Please choose...</option>
  <option value="Ubuntu Server 18.04">Ubuntu Server 18.04</option>
  <option value="Ubuntu Server 16.04">Ubuntu Server 16.04</option>
  <option value="Ubuntu Server 14.04">Ubuntu Server 14.04</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control location" name="location">
<option value="Please choose..." selected>Please choose...</option>  <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
  <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="Sao Paulo">São Paulo</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right btn-buynow" data-shoppy-product="ewAfime" data-shoppy-os="" data-shoppy-location="" disabled>Buy now</button>
```

And the JS Validation is as follows:

```
$(".os,.location").change(function() {
    if ($(".os").val() != "Please choose..." && $(".location").val() != "Please choose...") {
      $('.btn-buynow').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
```

Let me know if this works out for you.